# Why Firefox can't debug Vue component that packed by webpack but Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, frontend

In webpack.config.js, I use:

```
devtool: '#source-map'
```

and i make a test Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click='test'>test</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'test',
    methods: {
        test () {
            let num = 1       // breakpoint in here
            num += 10
            console.log(num)  // to make sure code has been executed
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In Chrome, I make a breakponit, and it can work fine when i click the "test" button.

However I make a same case in Firefox, whatever I click the "test" button, the breakpoint has no effect.And in the console, the value of "num" are printed.

So it was a bug of Firefox or configuration's mistake of mine? How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found any solution on this? I migrated to firefox but i cannot use debugger for this same scenario